# Using FortranForm

Tags: fortran

I need to use in Fortran, matrices that I create in Mathematica, therefore, I need to format them, so that Fortan can understand them. I focus on the simplest example:

Let's say I have tha matrix A created in Mathematica

```
A = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
```

Then, I am supposed to use FortranForm

```
FortranForm[A]
```

which gives as an output

```
List(List(1,1),List(1,1))
```

My question is, what do I do with this now? This cannot be the input file to Fortran, since this should be only numbers as far as I am aware.
It could be that, the input file to Fortran is the out put of

```
List(List(1,1),List(1,1))
```

but this is nothing in Mathematica, so it does not give any output.

Any help please?

Comment: I think FortranForm was made for converting formulae to a form that's either usable with Fortran or is easy enough to edit to make it usable with Fortran.  If it encounters a function it doesn't support, it keeps its name and uses parentheses for the call.  In this case it thinks List is a function.

Comment: I had the same problem while converting an analytical matrix to fortran. It took me several regular expressions to get the output in a reasonable form. The biggest problem was the conversion of literal constants to double precision while list indices should remain integer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FortranForm` is really pretty limited. You need to do something like this:

```
 A = {{1, 1. 10^7}, {2., 1}}
 StringJoin@{"A=reshape((/", 
       Riffle[ ToString[FortranForm[#]] & /@ Flatten[A] , ","], 
          "/),shape(a))"}
```

> "A=reshape((/1,1.e7,2.,1/),shape(a))"

or

```
 StringJoin@{"data a/", 
     Riffle[ ToString[FortranForm[#]] & /@ Flatten[A] , ","], "/"}
```

> "data a/1,1.e7,2.,1/"

( you likely want to `Transpose[A]` as well )

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, but, as far as I am aware, (and actually have checked) is that, if I want, Fortran to read my matrix A by using read* , the input file should be just a list of numbers with no comas, no brackets...and then Fortran will give them the position in the matrix according to the dimensions I set in the program

Comment: oh..for that just `Export[filename,A,"Table"]` and fortran will read it with a simple `read(unit,*)a` . (again you might want to `Transpose[A]` first.)

Comment: You mean, read(unit,*), A      ?

Comment: the extra comma is not needed. If you are reading from standard input you could use `read*,a` as well.

Comment: @george2079 I am afraid you have made a mistake. Because fortran stores arrays as column major. for example `{{1,2},{3,4}}` in mathematica is actually `reshape((/1,3,2,4/),(/2,2/))` in fortran. You have to transpose the list first

Comment: I did say to transpose at the bottom. Probably should have elaborated as to why.